# Can anyone explain STP mangling?

Tags: spanning-tree

There's nothing written about it on the internet. Nothing about if it's currently possible to carry out, or how to counter it. Just this definition copy pasta everywhere:

> STP (Spanning-Tree Protocol) mangling refers to the technique used for
>   the attacker host to be elected as the new root bridge of the spanning
>   tree. The attacker may start either by forging BPDUs (Bridge Protocol
>   Data Units) with high priority assuming to be the new root, or by
>   broadcasting STP Configuration/Topology Change Acknowledgement BPDUs
>   to get his host elected as the new root bridge. By taking over the
>   root bridge, the attacker will be able to intercept most of the
>   traffic.

Also another question, what's a Configuration/Topology Change Acknowledgement BPDU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switches send out BPDUs (Bridge Protocol Data Units) to elect a root bridge. Initially, every switch assumes it is the root bridge,until it receives a superior BPDU. This is an ongoing process. Also, when a switch notices a change in the topology (link up/down), it will send TCN (Topology Change Notification) BPDUs.

If you haven't correctly configured, or your switches don't support, the available STP security/stability measures (e.g. root guard), an attacker could send out BPDUs in order to take over from the root bridge. STP creates a loop-free environment by having the switches send traffic toward the root bridge. An attacker could have traffic sent toward it.

Comment: So all switches have root guard by default?

Comment: No, not at all. Cisco has root guard, and other STP security/stability protocols, but not all vendors have anything likes this, although most enterprise-grade vendors have these types of things.

Comment: Oh. Do 3com 4400 and 4900 switches have them?

Comment: I don't specifically know about those switches.